# Express.js session undefined in method put

Tags: node.js, session, express

Building an API with node and express. In my "home" route i set a session with a users id. 
When i want to add and update information on a user i want to access the session to know which user to update. In my `get` routes i can access the session, but in my route with `put` method its always undefined. Why is this?

```
app.get('/users/:id/spots', spot.findSpotsByUserId); //I set the session in this method
app.get('/spots/:id', spot.findById);
app.put('/userspot/spot/:spotId/add'', spot.addUserSpot);

exports.findSpotsByUserId = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id; //Should ofc be done with login function later  

    db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, user) {

            if (err) {
                res.send({'error':'Couldnt find user'});
            } else {
                req.session.userId = id;//<----- sets session
                console.log("SESSION",req.session.userId);               
            }
......}



exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Get spot: ' + id);
    console.log("SESSION!",req.session.userId);// <----prints the id!
    db.collection('spots', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
            res.send(item);
        });
    });
};

exports.addUserSpot = function(req, res) {

    var user = req.session.userId;
    var spot = req.params.spotId; 
    console.log("SESSION!",req.session.userId);// always UNDEFINED!

//........}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Mongo. Can we how you're setting up your express.session()?

Comment: @ThrowsException I have updated the code so you can se where the session is set. Its true that im using mongo. Its strange because its only undefined in my put method

Comment: are you setting up your app.use(express.session...) and app.use(express.cookieParser...) variables in your application? Without seeing all of your app.use statements it appears those are not being set up right. you may want to take a look at this http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions

Comment: @ThrowsException Yes i have that setup. The session is working, i get access to it in my `get`route, but in my `put`method(addUserSpot) its always undefined

Comment: When you are testing, are you setting the cookie properly? Maybe you are not persisting the sessions between the client calls

Comment: @randunel I set the session in my findSpotsByUserId method. I then go to the client address `/users/:id/spots` and the server logs the session so its set. Then i try to curl my put method addUserSpot and the server logs that session is undefined.

Comment: I am talking about the client, not the server. Are you properly setting + sending the cookie in the client application?

Comment: @randunel Im not setting any cookie at the client. I feel a little bit lost here. Do i need to set cookie at the client? Is it realy safe to set a cookie with an id like a users id at the client? When a user is logged in, the server sets a session. Then the server always know whos user data to edit by req.session when ever a form in the client is posted.

Comment: You don't need to keep the user id or any other information in the cookie. You only need the session ID, otherwise the server cannot distinguish between multiple client calls. What client are you using? If it is a browser, then it should automatically handle all the cookies. If it is a custom application, then you need to handle the cookies yourself.

Comment: @randunel Ok. The client is a webbrowser. So how do i access the session from the client? I want the session only so the server knows what user to update. Im not sure if i should use sessions or just parameters so i started this question [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013299/post-form-from-underscore-template-to-express-js-api) on how to update a user from the client

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `req.params.userId`, not `req.session`.

The session is persisted between multiple calls, and it has no connection to the `params` object. You can set `req.session.userId` in a previous call and access it here, but I don't think this is what you want.

Try this:

```
exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    req.session.test = "from findById";
    ...
};

exports.addUserSpot = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.test, req.params.userId);
    ...
};
```

Comment: I use `req.params.spotId` to get the spot but the userId i want to get from `session`. `/userspot/spot/123/add` for exampel

Comment: Basically i want the session with userId to be like a global variable that i easly can access whenever i want to change the data related to that user. In that way I dont have to pass the userId with parameters in the url. Makes this sense?