# Post form to an API with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, underscore.js

Im not good with forms. How do you send a post form from an underscore.js template to an express.js API with javascript? I try with the .submit() but it doesnt work. Im using jQueryMObile so the form is inside a data-role page.

The route on server:

```
app.put('/users/:userId/spot/:spotId/add', spot.addUserSpot);
```

The form:

```
    <form id="follow" method="put">
                    <input type="hidden" id="spot" value="<%= this.model._id %>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="user" value="<%= user %>">
                    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Follow spot">
    </form>

    jQuery("#follow").on('submit', function(){
                    console.log("SUBMITTED");
                    var spot = jQuery("#user").attr("value");
                    var user = jQuery("#spot").attr("value");
                    jQuery("#follow").attr("action", "/users/"+user+"/spot"+spot+"/add");
                    alert(jQuery("#follow").attr("http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/"+user+"/spot/"+spot+"/add"));

   });%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers do not support PUT, but express.js has a built-in solution. Just add a method override to your form:

```
<form id="follow" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

Comment: Oh thanks! The problem is my submit function is never fired. Its like the page only refresh when i click submit button. I dont know if jQuery Mobile is interfering with something?

Comment: Does `jQuery(document).on('submit', '#follow', function() {` work?